# Auto-Draggable Variables

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to be able to drag & drop variables (such as floats, integers, maybe even classes) in the Inspector view. So that if I have `FirstScript`  and `SecondScript` I could easily drag & drop variables between them so that they can change each others' data. I need this to create more modular workflow.

I know that `ScriptableObjects` allow similar functionality but I need to create them manually through `Create` button in `Inspector`. Instead I want this to happen automatically.

This should look something like scripts below. So that I could drag the `original_float` to `float_to_change` field right in the `Inspector`.

```
// First Component

public class FirstScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DraggableFloat original_float = 5.0f;
}

// SecondComponent

public class SecondScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    public DraggableFloat float_to_change;

    public void ChangeFloat()
    {
        // The value of original_float is changed through reference
        float_to_change += 10.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could modify the InpsectorGUI of SecondScript with an Editor script where you could have buttons for each copyable variable in the scene. In order to find these copyable variables you could use c#'s reflection mechanisms.

Comment: https://github.com/dbrizov/NaughtyAttributes 

This repo may help you.